# I am installing a AO Smith 19gal water heater with hot an cold connections on the side and the top

Tags: water-heater

I am installing an AO Smith 19 gallon water heater model E6-19c-15SV.  Can I use the cold "in" connection with the side "out" hot connection on the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two choices they just add a tee inside the tank.

The side and top both end at the same place.

Just remember to seal the two connections not used, if not already sealed.

Answer (score 0):

You must run flow in the direction required by the instructions.  Otherwise it won't work.

And... Technology Connections just put out a video on how those work. Watch some of it and think about how that would behave if you swapped inlet and outlet.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bm7L-2J52GU